# Mapping issue with multiple lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists `J1` and `A1`. I have another list `J2` with some elements from `J1`. I want to print corresponding values from `A1` using `A2`. I present the current and expected output.

```
J1 = [1, 7, 9, 11]
A1 = [2.1,6.9,7.3,5.4]

J2 = [1, 9]
J2,A2=map(list, zip(*((a, b) for a, b in zip(J2,A1))))
print(A2)
```

The current output is

```
[2.1, 6.9]
```

The expected output is

```
[2.1, 7.3]
```

Comment: Are you sure you understand the effect of *zip(J2,A1)* ?

Comment: What if values of interest in J1 are repeated? What if A1 and J1 are not the same length? What if a value of interest is not in J1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another variation, closer to the original:

```
A2 = [a for a,j in zip(A1,J1) if j in J2]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
J1 = [1, 7, 9, 11]
A1 = [2.1,6.9,7.3,5.4]

J2 = [1, 9]

A2 = [A1[J1.index(a)] for a in J2]
print(A2)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Define a `dict` using the keys in `J1` and the values in `A`, then use the values in `J2` as keys to look up in the new `dict`. [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) will be useful.

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> d = dict(zip(J1, A1))
>>> A2 = list(itemgetter(*J2)(d))
>>> A2
[2.1, 7.3]
```